# Why is the reference generated from a WCF service different between projects?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2013

I have two ASP.NET projects inside one solution in VS. To each project I have added the same WCF service reference and all was good. However just now I have updated the wcf service then updated the wfc service reference in each project. In one project, the Reference.cs contains two partial classes (which good) while the other project after the update only contains one of the partial classes and hence the project no longer builds.

Without looking at my code, is there any suggestions you may have to resolve this. Also, the changes I made to the WCF service before this break seemed insignificant (just added a couple of logic statements).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Kayla

Comment: Probably stating the obvious here but just in case... have you closed and restarted Visual Studio, then tried again to update the Service Reference? Just in case some file could not be overwritten or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The clients generated in your projects are not the same classes (although they may look the same, they are in separate namespaces).

The easiest solution is to remove the existing service references, create a new project, add a service reference to it, and then add **project** references from your two existing projects to the new project. Then fix the broken namespace references that will appear in your errors window.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will try this tomorrow at work. I just have a question regarding what you said to do with the namespaces. I am trying to add the exact same WCF service reference to two different projects. If I am referencing the service reference in their respective projects, wouldn't the namespaces be OK? Thanks again :)

Comment: I think we'd need a lot more detail to work out why the partial classes are different - it could be due to differences of configuration, versions or developer written code. I think that the main problem was that they could be different in the first place, considering that they are in the same solution.